# How to make custom 404 page for the Detail view with <int:pk>, if the instance not found?

Tags: django, django-forms

so the error is Page not found(404) when I am requesting the instance that does not exist. I would like to customize the 404 page, instead of displaying the general error.

Here is my new_wiki/urls

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import IndexView, InstanceView, AddPostView, EditPost


urlpatterns = [
    # path('', views.index, name="index")
    path('', IndexView.as_view(), name="index"),
    path('instance/<int:pk>', InstanceView.as_view(), name="instance"),
    path('create_post/', AddPostView.as_view(), name="create_post"),
    path('instance/edit/<int:pk>', EditPost.as_view(), name="edit_post")
]
```

And my InstanceView class

```
class InstanceView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'new_wiki/instance.html'
```

I have tried to use the solution from Django documentation:

```
def detail(request, post_id):
    try:
        p = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Poll does not exist")
    return render(request, 'new_wiki/instance.html', {'post': p})
```

but it is still returning the same 404 page. Thank you

Comment: Instead of raising a HTTP404, you return a page with status 404, so something like `render(request, 'some/template.html', status=404)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use **get_object_or_404** method

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
def detail(request, post_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=post_id)
    return render(request, 'new_wiki/instance.html', {'post': p})
```

Please check this is working.

Answer (score 2):

You can just render a page with a 404 status:

```
def detail(request, post_id):
    try:
        p = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        return render(request, 'new_wiki/404error.html', status=404)
    return render(request, 'new_wiki/instance.html', {'post': p})
```

If you want to specify a custom 404 page in general, you specify the [**`handler404`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.handler404) in the `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import IndexView, InstanceView, AddPostView, EditPost


urlpatterns = [
    # path('', views.index, name="index")
    path('', IndexView.as_view(), name="index"),
    path('instance/<int:pk>', InstanceView.as_view(), name="instance"),
    path('create_post/', AddPostView.as_view(), name="create_post"),
    path('instance/edit/<int:pk>', EditPost.as_view(), name="edit_post")
]

handler404 = views.handler404
```

In the view you can then analyze the `exception` parameter and return a specific

```
# app/views.py

from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound

def handler404(request, exception):
    data = exception.args
    if data:
        return HttpResponseNotFound(data[0])
    return HttpResponseNotFound('some text')
```

This then works if you set the [**`DEBUG`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEBUG) to `False`:

```
# settings.py

DEBUG = False
```

In that case the handler will be invoked when you raise a `Http404`.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer, I have used the second solution.